# get_the_ID() fails the first time, returns a value the second time it's called

Tags: posts, custom-field

I'm using `get_the_ID()` when creating an email. The first time that an email is sent using a post for the content, `get_the_ID()` returns nothing.

If I resend an email with that same post, it will return the post ID properly.

I'm just trying to pull a custom_field from the meta, is there also a different approach to this that I'm missing?

Is there some weird behavior with the method that I don't understand.  Here's my code snippet.

```
 <?php 
     wp_reset_postdata();
     $postid = get_the_ID();
     $key = 'trackingnumber'; 
     $tracking_number = get_post_meta( $postid, $key, true ); ?>

<p><span class="trackingnumber">Here is your Canada Post tracking number: </span><a style="font-weight:bold;" href="http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?trackingNumber=<?php echo $tracking_number ?>"><?php echo $tracking_number ?></a>
```

Comment: you'll probably need to post more of the code than that.

Comment: ok, I've put the whole code snippet in the question now.  As you can see, I'm also trying to reset the postdata before getting the ID, but that's not helping either

Comment: Where does this happen precisely? What is the main or secondary loop in play here?